# Update price of a product in a custom template woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update the price from a **custom page template**. In my custom template I am writing these :

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    switch ($post_id) {
        case '70':
            echo the_title().'<br>';

            $get_the_product_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);

            $updated_product_price = $get_the_product_price+30;

            update_my_price($post_id , $updated_product_price);

        default:

            break;
    }

endwhile;
```

In **functions.php** I wrote this :

```
function update_my_price( $post_id , $updated_product_price) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $updated_product_price );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_my_price' );
```

The problem is Price is not being updated.

Any thought ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: this is not good... if this would update, your price will increase by 30 in each page visit... your price will be 3000+ on 100 page visit

Comment: I am just doing a test for my project. I'll have condition later.

Comment: It might be a priority problem. Can you try to change to `add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_my_price', 10, 2 );`

Comment: Why don't you try to replace `update_my_price($post_id , $updated_product_price);` directly by `update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $updated_product_price );` and you don't use your function  `update_my_price()`. It could work… Also you have to test `$get_the_product_price` and `$updated_product_price`, to be sure that the problem don't come from those variables.

Comment: `woocommerce_process_product_meta` this action hook is reserved within admin area only.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tried it too but did not work. Can you please tell me how other people updates the price of a product within the product page like fancy product designer plugin ?

Comment: @zipkundan Is there any way what we can implement like the way I need ?

Comment: You may have a look to [Woocommerce Product Price not saving or updating correctly](https://wedevs.com/support/topic/woocommerce-product-price-not-saving-or-updating-correctly/) related to [**this one**](https://wedevs.com/support/topic/edit-not-updating-custom-fields/). And look also at [**this one**](https://wedevs.com/support/topic/edit-not-updating-custom-fields/).

Comment: I did the same thing man ! It does not work.